# Spatial join Polygons by their centroid in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3, spatial-join

I am trying to spatially join two tables containing polygons (let's call them table A and table B) so the ID of table A is joined to the table B only if the polygon centroids of table A are inside the polygons of table B.

Hope it makes sense?

I tried the spatial join, but the only option I could select is if the polygons of A are completely within the polygons B (second radio button) which is something I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use spatial join from ArcToolbox, which has the option that you need "Have their centroid in" located under the `Match Option`, as you can see below:

[image]

You can find the tool from `ArcToolbox -> Analysis Tools -> Overlay -> Spatial Join`